# Override space with own code, and potentially the space

Tags: function, vim, text-editor, key-bindings

I need to remap `<Space>` to run `MyFunction()` (in normal mode), and then depending on the result of processing of `MyFunction()`, it should be possible for it to work as normal space, i.e. move cursor right. How to accomplish this?

Exmaple: cursor is at "[ ]", pressing space changes that to "[x]", cursor doesn't move.

Example: cursor is at "a word", pressing space moves cursor right (normal mode).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
nnoremap <expr> ...
```

is what you are looking for.

E.g. if your `MyFunc()` return a boolean, you can do `:nnoremap <expr> <space> MyFunc()?"\<space>":"\<CR>"` So this maps space to normal space or Enter depends on the result of `MyFunc()`

You can also let your `MyFun()` return a string, then you can directly use it in key mapping.

read `:h :map-expr` for details.